# Loop over relation with eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have `Category` model that have defined relation:

```
public function entries() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Entry','entries_categories');
}
```

When I use:

```
$category = Category::find(8);

echo $category->name."<br />";
$entries  = $category->entries()->get();

foreach ($entries as $e) {
    echo $e->domain."<br />";
}
```

it works fine - displays what it should.

But when I try to use eager loading:

```
$category = Category::with('entries')->find(8);

echo $category->name."<br />";
foreach ($category->entries as $e) {
    echo $e->domain."<br />";
}
```

I get the following error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

And if I change the code to:

```
$category = Category::with('entries')->find(8);

echo $category->name."<br />";
foreach ($category->entries() as $e) {
    echo $e->domain."<br />";
}
```

I get no error, but loop is not executed even once.

How to display data in loop for Eager loading? In all cases  almost the same query to database is run and there are data if I manually run the query in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: You must have some collision in `entries` call. You can't loop through `entries()` for it's a relation object. However, with `belongsToMany` you can always use it in a foreach loop, as long as `$category->entries` is in fact calling the relation as a dynamic property. That said, check what collides there (accessor? property?) **BTW** If you want to play with Eloquent, better use `artisan tinker` in cli, instead of calling it in the browser.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk You can add it as answer, I'll accept that. I had an `entries` column in my table in database to store number of entries that belongs to category (never used so far) that's why it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have a collision in your model, eg. property / db field / accessor that is called when you use

```
$category->entries;
```

So it does not call [dynamic property](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#dynamic-properties) which returns a `Collection`, that could be used in a foreach loop.

```
// this works, because it explicitly calls the relation
foreach ($category->entries()-get() as $e)

// this would work the same way if there wasn't name collision
// because under the hood it would call
// $category->entries()->getResults(), which does the same as get() on this relation
foreach ($category->entries as $e)
```